# Selenium WebDriver проверить расположение элемента в Assert

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, test-automation

На странице есть 2 элемента, два прямоугольника и кнопка, которая меняет их местами. Структура примерно следующая:

```
>div class="content-sections"
   >div id=1
   >div id=2
```

Как проверить в assert поменялись ли объекты id=1 и id=2 местами?

Позицию секций можно узнать по:

Позиция 1)

```
class=   section-index-0
```

Плзиция 2)

```
 class=  section-index-1
```

Comment: нужен алгоритм только? на каком языке?

Comment: @SeniorPomidor, java. Да, только алгоритм

Answer (score 1, accepted):

достаточно проверить на существование элемента в определенных позициях и их аттрибуты

```
WebElement elm1 = driver.findElement(By.css("div.content-sections > div:nth-child(1)");
WebElement elm2 = driver.findElement(By.css("div.content-sections > div:nth-child(2)");
Assert.assertTrue(elm1.getAttribute("id").equals("1"));
Assert.assertTrue(elm2.getAttribute("id").equals("2"));
```

Comment: Ну и что тут проверено будет? Что первый дочерний будет с id 1, а второй с id 2? Зачем нам эта информация? Не факт, что при нажатии кнопки порядок в DOM меняется. В вопросе указано, что порядок можно по названию класса определить

Comment: затем, что мы пытаемся определить что первый элемент имеет id == 1

Answer (score 0):

За корректность кода не ручаюсь (не силен в Java), но алгоритм такой:

```
   // Получаем текущие позиции элементов (названия классов)
   elem1Position = driver.findElement(By.css("div.content-sections > div#1").getAttribute("class");
   elem2Position = driver.findElement(By.css("div.content-sections > div#2").getAttribute("class");
    // Нажимаем кнопку
    button.click()
    // Проверяем, что класс у первого элемента соответствует классу второго элемента до нажатия. И наоборот для второго элемента
    Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.css("div.content-sections > div#1").getAttribute("class").equals(elem2Position));
    Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.css("div.content-sections > div#2").getAttribute("class").equals(elem1Position));
```

Comment: только вот дочерный элемент не имеет аттрибута class и ты поймаешь NullPointerException

Comment: @SeniorPomidor Почему? В вопросе сказано, что позиция дочернего элемента как  раз определяется по классу `class=section-index-0 `